# Get Image URL from API in Thymeleaf src tag

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an API like:

```
<IP>:<Port>/getProfilePic/{userName}
```

This API just returns a CDN URL as a String where image for this user can be found. In Thymeleaf template, I am doing:

```
<img class="chat-message-author-pic" 
    th:src="@{'/getProfilePic/' + ${message.getUsername()}}" 
    width="15px" height="15px"/>
```

Of course the response is being treated as the image content instead of a URL from where the image should be loaded. Like, for one of the user, the tag in browser appear as:

```
<img class="chat-message-author-pic" width="15px" height="15px" 
    src="/getProfilePic/shubham">
```

How can I use Thymeleaf templating so it call the API, get the String which should act as a URL for `src` tag? Will this work in Javascript function as well which appends HTML to a `div` when I do this:

```
<img class="chat-message-author-pic" 
    th:src="@{/getProfilePic/' + username + '}" 
    width="15px" height="15px"/>' + ...
```

Comment: If you are creating DOM element and appending to DIV using JavaScript then you have to use regular `img src` attribute and it should work as long as the image is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf isn't the way to go here.  Instead you should:

1. In the controller for `/getProfilePic/shubham`, just return the image content (using java to retrieve the remote image and pass it along).

or

2. Put the url in a different attribute.  Something like this:

`<img class="chat-message-author-pic" width="15px" height="15px" th:data-location="@{/getProfilePic/{user}(user=${message.username})}">`

Then use JavaScript to populate the `src` attributes.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.chat-message-author-pic').each(function (i, e) {
    $.get($(e).data('location'), function(data) {
      $(e).prop('src', data);
    }, 'text');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean I should return a `File` object from the API?

Comment: Something like this for example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

Comment: In Thymeleaf with above image tag, I am facing this issue: https://imgur.com/a/QGTWAoO. Exception I am getting is `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986`.

Comment: I'm not sure what that error means... I tested it with thymeleaf 3/spring boot and everything worked for me.  Is your thymeleaf set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is. All of my pages work fine with Thymeleaf, it's a big project.

Comment: Let me try the first way. What should I return, the `File` object or a `byte[]` maybe?